# how to get list from a database where name = "Elephant" in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

Hi guys I want to get Elephants list from database I am using this code but the query is wrong
 when I run the same query MesaSQLite it is working please help me

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getAnimalsList
{   
    [animalsList removeAllObjects];

    sqlite3_stmt* statement;
    const char *sql;
    sql =  "select * from animals where name = Elephant";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }


    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {

        NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(statement,0);     
        Animal *animalObject = [[Animal alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey database:database];
        [animalsList addObject:animalObject];
        [animalObject release];
        animalObject = nil;

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    printf("\n The animals list count is :%d",[animalsList count]);
    return animalsList ;

}
```

When I used 'SELECT * From animals where name = "Elephant";" in SQLite it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not enclosing Elephant in quotes in your code, try

```
sql =  "select * from animals where name = 'Elephant'";
```

Comment: Thank you its working. Can you please provide sql stmt for passing the animal name -(NSMutableArray*)getAnimalsList:(NSString *)animalName{ sql = "Select * from animals where name = animalName";

Comment: I got it by the following code -(NSMutableArray*)getAnimalsList:(NSString *)animalName
{ 
 [animalsList removeAllObjects];
 
 sqlite3_stmt* statement;
 
    
 NSString *sql =  [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select * from animals where name = '%@'",animalName];
 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
 {
  NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
 }